# maven test don't run tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, m2eclipse

I've a maven project in my eclipse (m2eclipse)
i want to write some simple tests:

```
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

If I run Maven test (Run-->Run As-->Maven test) in Eclipse it came the expected output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running app.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.076 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   test(app.AppTest): Not yet implemented

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

But, if I try the same via "mvn test" in my console, the tests are not execute:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I run the test via `mvn test`?

Comment: Maybe Test is junit test - maven use testng by default if you have both in path.

Comment: I've add the dependency for JUnit and the plugin surefire, how can i change the default?

Comment: Compare maven versions - from eclipse and console. Install maven 3.0.4 in your system and check again. Eclipse plugin just use version 3 I think

Comment: my m2eclipse use a external maven installation (the same like i try the test) of version 3.0.4

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your test case is located in the `src/test/java` directory, and not in `src/main/java`. The `surefire` plugin will only run test cases located under `src/test/java`.

Create this directory in Eclipse, move the test case there and then do a *Maven > Update Project Configuration*, which will add `src/test/java` as a source folder in Eclipse.

When running Maven from command line, it should also show that it's compiling test classes. Make sure that this is happening, e.g.

```
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /dummy-project/target/test-classes
```

Comment: i've checked this, no changes

Comment: Where is your test case located?

Comment: my test-location: "src/test/java" in package app, class AppTest

Comment: Is your test class getting compiled? See my example above for how this should show.

Comment: Another issue, which does not apply here, but will be valuable for other people checking the same question:  Make sure the class name where the tests live ends in Tests (e.g.  MyProjectTests).  Otherwise the tests won't be picked from the command line by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following command:

`mvn clean generate-sources install`

Answer (score 0):

For someone having the same issue that is not finding an answer in this post, which is the top result in Google, check your imports for the @Test annotation.

I had `import org.junit.Test;` which sounds about right but with that my tests aren't run. Tried with `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` and it works.

Seems quite obvious since tests are being run by TestNG...